# how to call method of another sibling component - angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, siblings

I have two sibling components in one page need to call second component function and pass some value `onClick` event of first component link.

```
<my-container>
    <sibling-component1></sibling-component1> // this has link to call function
    <sibling-component2></sibling-component2> // this has function
</my-container>
```

code link : https://codepen.io/sandeep821/pen/aWQXZx?editors=1111

Comment: Re-factor the model and its function from component1 into a service. Then have component2 call the function in that service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fond the Solution (Communication between collaborating directives in Angular) : http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/25/communication-between-collaborating-directives-in-angular/